# How to sort Mongoose results depending on whether it's a $regex or $ text in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `REST API` Call like `/item/search` which has some query parameters attached to it.

The user can search for `entire term` or just `3 or more characters` of a term.

The `Node.JS` exports function is as follows,

```
exports.getSearchedItems = function(req,res){
var searchText = req.query.q;
var searchedString = searchText.replace(/ /g,"|");

var nameRegex = new RegExp('\\b' + searchedString + '.*', 'i');

Item.find()
    .or([
         {$text: {$search: searchText } },
         {'name': {$regex: nameRegex } },
         {'score':{'$meta': 'textScore'}
        ]
       )
    .sort({'score':{'$meta': 'textScore'}}
    .exec(function(err, items){
         if(err) console.log('Error Finding Query ' +err);
            res.send(items);
         });
};
```

A query Like `item/search?q=new+2`,

We get the below Error,

> Can't **canonicalize** query: **BadValue** must have **$meta projection** for all $meta sort keys

Is there any way I can do a partial `OR` full search yet maintain the textScore and sort my resulting mongoose documents as per that score.

Cheers and Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB's **`find()`** method can take a second optional argument indicating which fields to return and in your case of **`$text`** search, the special projection field **`$meta`** allows you to get back the score of the matched document so that you can sort on it.

Try modifying your `find()` query to include the query and the **`$meta`** projection as the `find()` arguments instead of the `or()` method:

```
Item.find(
    { 
        "$or":[ {"$text": {"$search": searchText } }, {"name": {"$regex": nameRegex } } ]
    }, 
    { 
        "score" : { "$meta" : "textScore"} 
    })
  .sort({"score": { "$meta": "textScore"} })
  .exec(function(err, items){
      if(err) console.log("Error Finding Query " + err);
      res.send(items);
  });
```

Comment: @theChinmay No worries :-)